# What is the best way to Null check input fields in the request object in Java?

Tags: java

I have a Code Like this:

Insurance Dto:

```
 private String accidentNo;
 private String birthDate;
 private String mobileNo;
 private String ssn;

 public InsuranceDto(String accidentNo, String birthDate, String mobileNo, String ssn) {
    this.accidentNo = accidentNo;
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
    this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
    this.ssn = ssn;
 }

 public InsuranceDto() {}

 public String getAccidentNo() {
    return accidentNo;
 }

 public void setAccidentNo(String accidentNo) {
    this.accidentNo = accidentNo;
 }

 public String getBirthDate() {
    return birthDate;
 }

 public void setBirthDate(String birthDate) {
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
 }

 public String getMobileNo() {
    return mobileNo;
 }

 public void setMobileNo(String mobileNo) {
    this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
 }

 public String getSsn() {
    return ssn;
 }

 public void setSsn(String ssn) {
    this.ssn = ssn;
 }
```

Main Method:

```
 InsuranceDto insuranceDto = new InsuranceDto();

 if (insuranceDto.getAccidentNo() == null)
     throw new RuntimeException("Enter AccidentNo.");
 if (insuranceDto.getBirthDate() == null)
     throw new RuntimeException("Enter BirthDate.");
 if (insuranceDto.getMobileNo() == null)
     throw new RuntimeException("Enter MobileNo");
 if (insuranceDto.getSsn() == null)
     throw new RuntimeException("Enter SSN");
```

So the Code Works but its Kind of Garbage and if I Add 3 Other Fields to **InsuranceDTO**, I Have to Edit the Entire Code to Validate them. Imagen if the Validation Policy Gets more Complicated and you Need to Validate two and/or more Fields in one If statement At Once.

So How Can I avoid this? Is There a Design Pattern or Something else to Make it Better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to reduce the amount of code, I can suggest you to Use Lombok `@Data`  annotation to get intrinsic getters and setters as well, this way you can avoid the whole getter setter methods which can reduce a lot of code. The way your InsuranceDto looks after you implement lombok is:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Build
public class InsuranceDto {
    @NotNull(message ="Accident Number must not be empty null")
    private String accidentNo;
    @NotNull(message ="Sample field 2 must not be empty null")
    private String samplefield2;
}
```

Lombok repository in Maven:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.22</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And to your question, In InsuranceDto, you can attach the @Data once you have the lombok, for example above the field accidentNo in the InsuranceDto, you can have

```
@NotNull(message ="Accident Number must not be empty null")
private String accidentNo;
```

This way you can completely avoid the null checks within your service class because it will throw a runtime exception when such a null values comes in even before hitting your service. The validation is automatic.

Edit:
If you're only trying to avoid null checks you can use Apache commons.

```
 org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate
```

Usage: If the accidentNo is null, an error is thrown with the string you give as a second argument.

```
Validate.notNull(accidentNo, "accidentNo cannot be null")
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I know this. my purpose is to remove the if statements and replace it with better solution. leave the "Validation" word behind. I just used it to explain the problem.

Comment: Okay. Added an update to the answer.

Comment: Also, you can try to avoid the null checks within the code altogether with the @NotNull(message ="Accident Number must not be empty null") and that is known to be widely used to avoid any in-service null checks

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. you see, I had a simple question "how can I avoid too many if statements". for that I thought it might be good to create a simple scenario and explain my intentions (its also my mistake). so the words like "Validation" and "Null checks" does not matter, the condition and the logic may be anything. stick to the part "remove the if statements" not with 3rd party libraries but with pure java, OOP and SOLID principles. I will post another question to make it more clear.